# Is it possible to make a Knockout bindingHandlers component?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout.  Is there a way to create a component that just adds a custom bindingHandler to the page?  I was thinking it would be cool to make a component people could drop on the page and get a new keyboard shortcut binding handler(see below example). Or am I not thinking in the knockout way?

**Example:**

```
<body>
    <keyboard-shortcuts></keyboard-shortcuts>
    <input type="text" data-bind="kb: {key: 'enter', run: submit}" />
</body>
```

**Update:**

I don't have a specific requirement here.  I'm just looking to see if this type of thing(see example above) is done in the knockout world.  If so does anyone have any example of how they have done this.  Thanks.

Comment: Seems like it should be possible since you can just add the bindingHandlers in the component's code. I couldn't tell you if it's the knockout way or not :) It's an interesting idea, though!

Comment: This is a *very* vague question I'm afraid. Have a look at the documentation, try to implement the feature you have in mind, and if you get stuck on a specific problem with a repro ask a question.

Comment: A few details would help us to answer: what are "component", "drop on the page"? PLease try to formalize the specifications of the feature you want to implement.

Comment: The short answer is yes, but need more details. For example, are the keyboard shortcuts specific to that binding / those elements, or the page? What should the binding do? Minimum verifiable etc etc

Comment: I have updated the post.  Hopefully that clarifies.  Is this kind of thing a standard practice in the knockout world?  Do you wrap your bindingHandlers in components?  Why/Why not?  If so how did you ensure proper component execution order?